# Flask-SQLAlchemy version3.1.x Old syntax doesnt work anymore

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My installed version : 3.1.1

To execute RAW MySQL query, the following used to work before I updated to 3.1.1. I hadbeen using it for 3 years now. Documentation says it is deprecated and will be removed soon.

`qres = db.get_engine(current_app, my_database_target).execute(qry_string)`

or to run on the default database,
`qres = db.get_engine(current_app).execute(qry_string)`

Now this gives the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sdfasdfasdf/projects/project_name/application/b_name/func/__init__.py", line 2330, in getQueryResults
    qres = db.get_engine(current_app).execute(qry)
  File "/home/sdfasdfasdf/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 737, in get_engine
    return self.engines[bind_key]
KeyError: <LocalProxy unbound>
```

[Documentation](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.engines) says use db.engines[key]

How to use that?
I have spent hours through documentation and doing dir() on a bunch of objects and ctrl+space using vscode to see what methods which object has.
None of the objects seem to have execute method like `db.engines[None].engine.execute(qry_string)`

Any help would be phenomenal.

I have tried to use the new syntax as suggested in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Update: There is a very simple way.
For default database,

```py
qres = db.engines[None].connect().execute(text(qry))
```

Or for specific database bind:

```py
qres = db.engines["bind_name_string"].connect().execute(text(qry))
```

Old answer: please disregard.
Ok. So nothing is given in documentation due to it being so recent. Here is the solution that is acceptable to me from what I gathered from issues on github.

Loop through `for key,engine in db.engines.items():`

Check whether key matches your bind name. key is None for default database.

Then:

```py
result = engine.connect().execute(text("Your Raw SQL Query"))
```

I really wish there was a way to directly connect to the desired engine by using the bind_key instead of looping through all the engines.